# how can i check duplicate data in my django database comparing with form data in generic view(Updateview)

Tags: django, django-2.0, django-2.1

I made a Updateview method in Django to update firstname, lastname, mobile etc..but how can I check the data received by the generic view through the form is previously exist in DB. For example, I want to avoid duplicating of mobile number with the model User in the database I tried by approaching def post() method, but I got a lot of errors can you teach me the exact way for avoiding duplicate data inserting

### View code

```
class UpdateMprofile(mixin1, mixin2, UpdateView):
    login_url = reverse_lazy('loginurlhere')
    model = User
    fields = ['first_name', 'last_name', 'mobile', 'avatar']
    success_url = reverse_lazy('redirectedviewurlhere')
```

Answer (score 0):

You should use [`unique=True`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.1/ref/models/fields/#unique) in the model field definition, then Django will check this automatically when validating the form.